# How to fix problem "Clickable elements too close together" in Google Search Console

Tags: css, button, google-search, google-search-appliance, google-search-console

I'm currently developing a website and just submitted it to Google SC. After indexing I got the error "Clickable elements are toot close together". I followed the [guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/accessibility/accessible-styles#multi-device_responsive_design) made by Google for Accessible styles, but the error persisted.

I made all "a" and "button" tags at least 48x48 px wide, and made sure they were at least 8px space between them.

The URL is: https://www.karlochanton.se

Any tips or fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add this css code as give below. I did'nt confirm, please try this.. If it does'nt work please share the screenshot

```
@media (max-width: 991px){
   .main-navigation .menu li {
      margin: 10px 0px;
   }
}
```